# Would it be easier to switch a project to Blazor United SSR from a Blazor Server or Blazor WASM app?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

We currently have an app written in Blazor Server but have the opportunity to clean up some of the architecture and move it over to a WASM app.

We are mindful that .net 8 and the new Blazor United model has recently launched and are questioning whether it is worth doing the work to switch to WASM or if it is easier to wait for .net8  ecosystem to mature and make the switch directly from Blazor Server to Blazor United.

Given that we can't easily switch from Server to WASM should demonstrate that this isn't an ideal build and in either case work will have to be carried out to make the switch.

Comment: So the *real* question is whether you should migrate to WASM before or after the migration to United? Migrate to United first, to ensure you have a working application, and *then* start making parts run on the client.

Comment: The blog post [How to migrate your Blazor Server app to .NET 8](https://jonhilton.net/blazor-net8-migration/) shows how to modify a Blazor Server project to work on Blazor 8.

Comment: You comments suggest that you are considering moving to `InteractiveAuto`- "clean up some of the architecture and move it over to a WASM app."  I've spent the last two weeks doing an in-depth assessment of component and service design in the new render mode environment.  This is a personal view, but there are some real design challenges in a hybrid Server/WASM environment.   Any design based on `Per page/component` Inter-Activity is probably a disaster waiting to happen unless you know components inside out and really know what you're doing.

Comment: I'm just starting a project migration from 3.1 to 8.0.  It will be `ActiveServer` with the interactivity location set to `Global` .

Comment: We're currently at .net6 server. We can do the work to go to .net7 WASM with a server api. Given that in the future there are potentially some nice performance gains to be had on .net8 Unified with some server side rendering / auto we are wondering if it is a help or hinderance to move to WASM or will we have to rollback changes to move to on to .net 8 from WASM?